# Why are orbitals are shown bubble shaped in the books when they exist in only in one particular dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, orbitals

I am utterly confused here: In our books orbitals $s$, $p$, $d$ are shown to be bubble or sphere like but ain't $s$-orbital exist only in $x$-axis so only a particular underline should be shown to denote it, just like when you mark open intervals in maths and the same goes for $p$-orbital for $x$, $y$ and $z$.

**So why draw a bubble like shape encompassing all the dimensions/axes/planes?**

Secondly, I can understand $d_{xy}$, $d_{xz}$, and $d_{yz}$ but what does $d_z^{2}$ and $d_z^{2} - y^{2}$ means ($x^{2} - y^{2}$ looks like $d_{xy}$, it just seems to be oriented by $90^{\circ}$)?

FYI, I am a high school student.

Comment: No.  All of the orbitals are three dimensional.   Can you explain why you think they exist only in 1d?  (Please be careful when typing ... do you mean "D" or "d"?   And please use MathJax.    [Here’s a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143293))

Comment: What is the reason you believe s orbitals only exist in one axis?

Comment: Respected Sir/Madame(s):I have told as such by my teacher.I first suspected this at first but then I consulted other chemistry/physics teacher who said s_x or p_x/d_x mean it exist only in x-axis/plane or along x-axis.I couldnt understand what they meant by along.That's why  assumed as such (tho it still seemed to me invalid whenever the equation integral wave dx dy dz = 1 comes to my mind since we integrate over 3-dimensional space).Kindly correct me wherever I am wrong with firm reasoning and enlighten me more on this @garyp

Comment: @garyp:I meant d ..Is there something D too?Can you tell me more about this

Comment: The subtext on something like $s_x$ *does* mean that it exists only in the x-dimension. However, when they told you that, they meant that specifically $s_x$ exists only in x. There may or may not be other components of $s$, such as $s_y$, which exist in other dimensions. What they told you was the truth, but misleading. They should have said it is the component of $s$ that exists solely in the x-dimension

Comment: in our books nothing such as s_y or s_z is mentioned and the diagram of s seems to be occupying the all 3 planes.Can you please elaborate more @Jim  and what about p_x,p_y and p_z,it appears to be 3D?

Comment: I used $s_x$ as an example. The important info to take away is just that the subtext x indicates it is the component of a value that is projected onto the x-axis.

Comment: @groak_master, The orbitals themselves are not 1 dimensional. The probability density is spread in such a way so as to have a symmetry axis. The px,py etc orbits, have their symmetry axis(their central axis in the diagrams) oriented in these directions. But the probability density cloud is three dimensional around this axis.

Comment: There's nothing special about the "D".  I just want to make sure it didn't mean something to you.  I wanted to make sure that it was what it appeared to be:  a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher may have misinterpreted your question about the s orbitals.  The s orbital never has a subscript.  It is always spherical.

As you move into the p and d orbitals, the subscripts describe the shape of the orbital.  For example $p_z$ is symmetric around the z axis.  This does not mean the electron is confined to the z axis, merely that the probability of finding it at a given place is higher as you get close to the z axis.  The shapes given for the orbitals are defined by probability.  When they show you a shell of an orbital, it is usually rendered as "the electron has a 90% probability of being within this volume at any moment" or some similar construction.

The exact meaning of the subscripts is a bit more complicated.  They deal with what are called [Cubic harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_harmonic).  These cubic harmonics are solutions to the angular momentum operator: meaning they keep spin angular momentum conserved.  The subscripts are actually key parts out of the cubic harmonic equations which uniquely identify that solution to the angular momentum operator.  I find they are related to symmetries in the shape of the orbital, but I don't yet know if that's coincidence or something fundamental about how the equations operate.

Also note that these are really probabilistic solutions for a the wave equation describing the electrons.  Wikipedia has a [very nice set of animations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Qualitative_understanding_of_shapes) showing an analogue of these orbitals in 2 dimensions using a drum to show the resonance of this wave.  It may be a helpful tool for developing a more intuitive grasp on what an orbital means.  It's not a 1:1 match to how electrons work, but its close enough that it may help with the visualization (and it comes with a verbal explanation of how the two connect, if you're curious)

Comment: You assume the questioner has accurately represented what their teacher said, despite their otherwise imperfect undetstanding. Perhaps the point was only that the single subscript orbitals may be biased along a single axis?

Comment: "pzpz  is symmetric around the z axis. This does not mean the electron is confined to the z axis, merely that the probability of finding it at a given place is higher as you get close to the z axis". since P-x and P_y both are symmetric doesn't it indirectly implies a sphere again? And what do interepret of the pear shape bulging outwards and what about d-orbital .I can't understand the later part can you please explain a toned-down version of it apporpriate for High school studentt?(I already mentioned my background in question but somebody edited out that part)

Comment: @groak_master P_x is symmetric around the x axis and P_y is symmetric around the y axis.  However, this is only one axis of symmetry.  A sphere (like the s orbital) is symmetric about any axis.  For example, if you have a cardboard tube, it is symmetric about one axis.  As for interpretations of the shapes, that's an entirely different field.  Interpreting them as anything except "the correct answer for a set of equations we believe governs electrons" is difficult.

Comment: You might be able to get some insight into what is going on from the patterns on a Chlandi plate (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YedgubRZva8).  Interpreting those patterns with respect to the sound waves on the Chlandi plate may be very helpful for helping you interpret the orbital shapes.  And, if not, it's a really pretty experiment!

Comment: @groak_master I fixed that over-zealous edit.  Let me know if you don't approve.

Comment: @CortAmmon and everyone:Now I get it,orbitals are 3d the supscript only implies that the space is symmetric around the x-axis (Is my understanding correct).But again the question arises aint' the p orbitals are overlapping with s say 2p with 1s and same for (n+1)p and np orbitals? so can we say that there's exchange of electron between electrons or that overlapping space has highest probability of finding an electron? Secondly x,y,z can be easily understood but what about x^2-y^2..what do we understand from that subscript?(in simple terms/tried wikipedia but couldn't grasp a thing)?

Comment: when we starts filling 2p orbital then  then what space will be filled first p_x ,p_y or p_z? or does it goes on randomly(since all of them are of same energy just different direction).And can electrons from p_x can jump into P_y or p_z..same for other orbitlas? @garyp :thanx,that's is suffiecient sir

Comment: And what is minimum or maximum or a fixed volume of a particular orbital?

Comment: Answering those questions in the best order I can think of: the orbital volumes we see depicted in textbooks are really an attempt to visualize a 3 dimensional probability field.  Its very difficult to show that on a 2d sheet of printed paper, so instead we pick some percentage (say 90%) and say "focus on the most likely places to find the electron and draw a boundary such that the electron is in the boundary 90% of the time."  Thus the minimum volume is nothing (a region for which the electron is found 0% of the time!).   The maximum volume, the 100% boundary, is actually...

Comment: ... the entire universe.  Obviously the 100% boundary isn't too useful, and you'll find that most of the time the electron stays very close to the nucleus.  As for the order they are filled, you can think of them as filling randomly.  In reality there will be *slight* differences in energy as the atom interacts with other atoms (the idealized model you're looking at is for a single atom in isolation), but for the purposes you will need to consider, they fill randomly.  Finally, you ask about the overlap between the orbitals, which is a very insightful question.  Yes, the space they...

Comment: ... take up overlaps.  However, the orbitals are distinguished in other ways (such as the quantum numbers assigned to each electron).  You can think of it similar to an intersection in traffic.  While both roads cross and use the same patch of asphalt, the directions cars take through that intersection are different.  Likewise, even though orbitals may share the same space, the electrons are in different orbitals (often different energy states), like being on different roads going through the same intersection.  Finally, as for "jumping" from p_x to p_z, you might be able to think of it...

Comment: ... that way.  Since the energy difference between them is slight, you may see an electron move from one to the other.  However, once you get deeper into the quantum mechanical definitions for how electrons behave, that simplified version won't cut it.  I'd say you can think of it as electrons jumping from p_x to p_z if it makes things easier for you, because in reality it won't matter much.  Just be ready to un-learn it if you find yourself needing to use QM because, like all other intuitive classical models, it's wrong.  It's just probably not worth your time to learn the "correct" version..

Comment: .. at the moment.  The intuitive model should suffice.

Comment: For this kind of response to a comment, you might consider editing your answer with a addendum "response to comment".   A bit easier to read (and probably type.)